# I get an error accross my sites in the IIS, Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've started getting this error in two (completely different) projects running in the IIS:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Apm.DataCollecting.Producers.Mvc.4.0, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +0
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +657
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +146


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.79.0
```

The error goes away if I wait a bit and then refresh the page a few times. I'm running Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015. As i said, the projects are completely different and have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: I am getting this as well. If I refresh 4 times I get my page. Can I ask, did you ever install the Application Insights client for your IIS? I did so and I am wondering if you and I have something left over from that.

Comment: I might have now that you mention it, did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a mess.  I had this same thing happen to me when I came back to a project I was working on 4-5 months ago.

The hint about application insights is what lead me to a solution, but uninstalling old application insights things didn't seem to solve it.

I solved it by installed in the Application Insights Status Monitor Preview (which I found in the Web Platform Installer within IIS by clicking "Install Application From Gallary" on the right side).  Then I ran that and my IIS application showed up.  I clicked on "configure" or whatever it was to make the status "Enabled" for it.  Then on the top of the Application Instaights Status Monitor Preview window I saw a thing that said I was running the Microsoft Monitor Agent or something like that, so I clicked the button there, and it told me to reset IIS.   After resetting IIS it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling the old insights client for IIS via Control Panel > Programs & Features.

Sorry but I don't remember the name of the program. I do remember it being fairly obvious as to which one it is though. There was only one.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app pool identity for the website is a member of the `Performance Monitor Users` group.

When running the Application Insights Status Monitor Preview, I saw a warning about my app pool identity not being a member of this group.

- Windows button
- type `mmc`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- File -> Add/Remove Snap-in...
- Select "Local Users and Groups", and click "Add >" and "Finish" in the second dialog
- Click "OK" in the original dialog
- Expand the "Local Users and Groups" node
- Expand the "Groups" node
- Double click the "Performance Monitor Users" group
- Add the identify of the app pool to the group